# How to calculate points using SQL not ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a rake task in my rails app which calculate bonuses:

```
namespace :all_bonus do
 desc "all given bonuses"
 task given_bonuses: :environment do
   points = 0
   Bonus.find_each do |bonus|
     points += bonus.points
   end

   puts Bonus.count
   puts points
 end
end
```

Find each method is loaded memory and I want to change it using SQL. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails how to sum columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874291/rails-how-to-sum-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
Bonus.sum(:points)
```

It translates into something like this SQL

```
SELECT SUM(`bonuses`.`points`) FROM `bonuses`
```