# Rails 5: Get complete count of orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display all orders and the total amount earned for the user in the reservations view.

I tried Reservation.count(:all), but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to count the orders from **all users?**

Here is my current Reservations controller without any changes:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:approve, :decline]

  def create
    wine = Wine.find(params[:wine_id])

    if current_user == wine.user
      flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht deinen eigenen Wein kaufen!"
    else

    start_date = Date.parse(reservation_params[:start_date])

    @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
    @reservation.wine = wine
    @reservation.price = wine.price
    @reservation.total = wine.price * @reservation.bottle
    # @reservation.save

  if @reservation.save
    if wine.Reservieren?
      flash[:notice] = "Anfrage versendet!"
  else
    @reservation.Bearbeitung!
    flash[:notice] = "Eroflgreich bestellt!"
  end
else
    flash[:alert] = "Can't make a reservation!"
  end

  end
    redirect_to wine
  end

  def your_orders
    @orders = current_user.reservations.order(start_date: :asc)
  end

  def your_reservations
    @wines = current_user.wines
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin == true
  end

  def your_upcoming_reservations
    @wines = current_user.wines
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin == true
  end


  def approve
    @reservation.Versendet!
    redirect_to your_reservations_path
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin == true
  end

  def decline
    @reservation.Abgelehnt!
    redirect_to your_reservations_path
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin == true
  end

  # Each Order Details
  def order_details
    @orders = current_user.reservations.order(start_date: :asc)
  end

  private

  def set_reservation
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :bottle)
  end
end
```

And this is my current view:

```
<div class="container-small">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Alle Bestellungen
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <% @wines.each do |wine| %>
          <% wine.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Erwartet am<br/>
                <%= reservation.start_date.strftime('%v') %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <p><%= reservation.status %></p>
                <div class="form-inline">
                  <% if reservation.Bearbeitung? %>
                    <%= link_to approve_reservation_path(reservation), method: :post do %> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></i> <% end %> |
                    <%= link_to decline_reservation_path(reservation), method: :post do %> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-lg"></i> <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= reservation.bottle %>x
                <%= link_to reservation.wine.wine_name, wine_path(reservation.wine) %><br/>
                Gesamt: <%= reservation.total %>€<br/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                Lieferung an<br/><br/>
                <span>
                  <%= link_to user_path(reservation.user) do %>
                    <%= reservation.user.fullname %><br/>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= reservation.user.location %>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails how to sum columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874291/rails-how-to-sum-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you should call:

```
@count = Reservation.count()
@total = Reservation.sum(:total)
```

And then in the view:

```
Reservations Count: <%= @count %>
Reservations Total: $ <%= @total %>
```

Ruby On Rails API docs for [count](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count)
and [sum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum)

Comment: Now it's appearing in the view, but both are showing 0

Comment: I used Reservation.count(:all) and Reservation.sum(:total) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternate syntax for explicitly saying that you are counting all the reservations is:

```
@count = Reservation.all.count
```

Personally, I like to be as obvious as possible about what I am expecting back from the query . Like, what if in the future you only wanted to count reservation which not canceled or maybe only count reservations on a specific month?

The rest of the answer by R. Sierra is on point.