# How to Show Sum of Column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display the sum of a column name "money" in my model Earning.
In the rails console, I can easily get the sum I want `Earning.sum(:money)` and it shows the sum.

**earnings_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @earnings = Earning.sum(:money)
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Earnings</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Money</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @earnings.each do |earning| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= earning.money %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', earning %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_earning_path(earning) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', earning, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Earning', new_earning_path %>
```

**It keeps throwing this error**

```
NoMethodError in Earnings#index
```

**What I've tried so far**

I am stumped. I've tried changing the index action to @earnings = earnings.sum(:money) and that gave me this error "NameError in EarningsController#index".  I also saw a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874291/rails-how-to-sum-columns) but since I think the issue is in my index.html.erb, it didn't help much.  As I said earlier the code works in the Rails Console.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I have edited for clarity hopefully. So, the problem is me trying to display a sum which occupies 1 field, when my table is trying to display multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are not using @earnings in a proper way, in your view you use earnings as a collecion of objects, but in controller @earnings are defined as a sum of money but you are not using it, if you really need this sum, you can set two instance variables fiest @earnings = Earning.all and the second one @money_sum = Earnings.sum(:money) and then you can display somewhere your sum as = @money_sum, then you can iterate by @earnings to create some linka in your view

Comment: Thanks! This worked although I had to change it to @money_sum = Earning.sum(:money)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something like this.

First in your controller you want to get all earnings records.

```
def index
  @earnings = Earning.all
end
```

Then in your view you iterate over all `@earnings` and spit out `earnings.money` as single value for each of your record.

If you want to get **total of all earnings** somewhere, you can do `@earnings.sum(:money)`, which will basically give you single value as total of all earnings - `Earning.all`.